# Football Management Program (AMERICAN) C++

Tags: c++, beginner, object-oriented, game

I have recently finished my first real C++ program. It is text based, but hey, what d'ya expect out of a student? So, I would like person(s) to review the code I have written. It ain't short, but I wouldn't call it a "long" program either.

I couldn't figure if I could attach a file or not, so I provide a link, and if you'd rather just copy and paste it, then here it is below...

Link - https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ihvmdhl9t22hqrj/AACq_3HxMaMn8lpop2kATtega?dl=0

Also, would love feedback. Again, I'm new, and yes it is very clunky and inefficient, but hey, I'm proud! Though, I would love some criticism. I honestly have hardly a clue what I'm doing, and just threw this thing together.

Without further adieu, enjoy!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <time.h> 
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int number, overall;
string team, nextgame;
int opponentoverall;
int score, score2, random, random2, random3, random4, random5, randoml;
float finalscore, finalscore2;
string choice;
int week = 1;
int i = 3;
int u = 0;
int randl;
int champ1, champ2;

int onet = 0;
int twot = 0;
int threet = 0;
int fourt = 0;
int fivet = 0;
int sixt = 0;
int sevent = 0;
int eightt = 0;
int ninet = 0;
int tent = 0;
int onev = 0;
int twov = 0;
int threev = 0;
int fourv = 0;
int fivev = 0;
int sixv = 0;
int sevenv = 0;
int eightv = 0;
int ninev = 0;
int tenv = 0;
string champname, champname2;
string prospect1 = "Jonas Hill - QB";
string prospect2 = "Kyle Matthew - DB";
string prospect3 = "Julius Brown - RB";
string prospect4 = "Reece David -  C";
string prospect5 = "Cole Anderson - FS";
string prospect6 = "Andy Tyler - WR";
string prospect7 = "Macus Reed - FB";
string prospect8 = "Elijah Moore - LB";
string prospect9 = "Larry Steel - RB";
string prospect10 = "Nicholas Dean - LB";
int oner = 0;
int twor = 0;
int threer = 0;
int fourr = 0;
int fiver = 0;
int sixr = 0;
int sevenr = 0;
int eightr = 0;
int niner = 0;
int tenr = 0;
int ones = 0;
int twos = 0;
int threes = 0;
int fours = 0;
int fives = 0;
int sixs = 0;
int sevens = 0;
int eights = 0;
int nines = 0;
int tens = 0;

string one = " ";
string two = " ";
string three = " ";
string four = " ";
string five = " ";
string six = " ";
string seven = " ";
string eight = " ";
string nine = " ";
string ten = " ";
int minutes = 120;

class Team
{
    public:
        string name;
        int overall, game;
        int win, loss;
        string week1, week2, week3, week4, week5, week6, week7, week8, next;
};



void start() {
    cout << string( 100, '\n' );
    cout << "Choose a School to Coach!" << endl;
    cout << "1- Tennessee" << endl;
enum Schools{ tennessee = 1,auburn,pennst };
        cin >> number;
            if(number == tennessee){
                team = "Tennessee";
                overall = 75;
            }
            
            
            
            
        
}


void mainmenu() {
    
    cout << string( 100, '\n' );
    cout << "FOR THE PLAYER EXPERIENCE, PLEASE PLAY IN FULL SCREEN" << endl;
    cout << "Be the Coach | College Football Manager" << endl;
    cout << "1 - Manage" << endl << "2 - Manual" << endl << "3 - Abort" << endl; 
enum Choices{ manage = 1,manual,abort };
    cin >> number;
        if(number == manage){
            start();
        }
    
}


int main()
{
    srand (time(NULL));
    int tut = 0;
int rands;
int onel = rand() % 30 + 1;
int two1 = rand() % 30 + 1;
int three1 = rand() % 30 + 1;
int four1 = rand() % 30 + 1;
int five1 = rand() % 30 + 1;
int six1 = rand() % 30 + 1;
int seven1 = rand() % 30 + 1;
int eight1 = rand() % 30 + 1;
int nine1 = rand() % 30 + 1;
int ten1 = rand() % 30 + 1;
int onec = rand() % 10 + 1;
int twoc = rand() % 10 + 1;
int threec = rand() % 10 + 1;
int fourc = rand() % 10 + 1;
int fivec = rand() % 10 + 1;
int sixc = rand() % 10 + 1;
int sevenc = rand() % 10 + 1;
int eightc = rand() % 10 + 1;
int ninec = rand() % 10 + 1;
int tenc = rand() % 10 + 1;
int addrat = 0;
        int Year = 1;
    Team Clemson;
    
    Clemson.name = "Clemson";
    Clemson.overall = 88;
    Clemson.win = 0;
    Clemson.loss = 0;
    
    Team Alabama;
    
    Alabama.name = "Alabama";
    Alabama.overall = 86;
    Alabama.win = 0;
    Alabama.loss = 0;

    
    Team Georgia;
    
    Georgia.name = "Georgia";
    Georgia.overall = 85;
    Georgia.win = 0;
    Georgia.loss = 0;

    
    Team Florida;
    
    Florida.name = "Florida";
    Florida.overall = 83;
    Florida.win = 0;
    Florida.loss = 0;


    Team NotreDame;
    
    NotreDame.name = "Notre Dame";
    NotreDame.overall = 80;
    NotreDame.win = 0;
    NotreDame.loss = 0;

    
    Team OhioState;
    
    OhioState.name = "Ohio State";
    OhioState.overall = 79;
    OhioState.win = 0;
    OhioState.loss = 0;

    
    Team MiamiFL;
    
    MiamiFL.name = "Miami FL";
    MiamiFL.overall = 77;
    MiamiFL.win = 0;
    MiamiFL.loss = 0;

    
    Team UNC;
    
    UNC.name = "UNC";
    UNC.overall = 75;
    UNC.win = 0;
    UNC.loss = 0;

    
    Team PennSt;
    
    PennSt.name = "Penn State";
    PennSt.overall = 72;
    PennSt.win = 0;
    PennSt.loss = 0;

    Team OklahomaSt;
    
    OklahomaSt.name = "Oklahoma State";
    OklahomaSt.overall = 70;
    OklahomaSt.win = 0;
    OklahomaSt.loss = 0;

    
    Team Auburn;
    
    Auburn.name = "Auburn";
    Auburn.overall = 68;
    Auburn.win = 0;
    Auburn.loss = 0;

    
    Team Tennessee;
    
    Tennessee.name = "Tennessee";
    Tennessee.overall = 65;
    Tennessee.win = 0;
    Tennessee.loss = 0;
    Tennessee.week1 = "Georgia";
    Tennessee.week2 = "Alabama";
    Tennessee.week3 = "OklahomaSt";
    Tennessee.week4 = "PennSt";
    Tennessee.week5 = "Auburn";
    Tennessee.week6 = "UNC";
    Tennessee.week7 = "MiamiFL";
    Tennessee.week8 = "OhioState";
    Tennessee.next = Tennessee.week1;
    
    mainmenu();
home:
    if(Alabama.overall > 100){
        Alabama.overall = 100;
    }
    if(Clemson.overall > 100){
        Clemson.overall = 100;
    }
    if(OhioState.overall > 100){
        OhioState.overall = 100;
    }
    if(NotreDame.overall > 100){
        NotreDame.overall = 100;
    }
    if(OklahomaSt.overall > 100){
        OklahomaSt.overall = 100;
    }
    if(MiamiFL.overall > 100){
        MiamiFL.overall = 100;
    }
    if(Auburn.overall > 100){
        Auburn.overall = 100;
    }
    if(UNC.overall > 100){
        UNC.overall = 100;
    }
    if(Florida.overall > 100){
        Florida.overall = 100;
    }
    if(PennSt.overall > 100){
        PennSt.overall = 100;
    }
    if(Georgia.overall > 100){
        Georgia.overall = 100;
    }
    if(Tennessee.overall > 100){
        Tennessee.overall = 100;
    }
        if(Tennessee.next == "Georgia"){
        opponentoverall = Georgia.overall;
    }else if(Tennessee.next == "Alabama"){
        opponentoverall = Alabama.overall;
    }else if(Tennessee.next == "OklahomaSt"){
        opponentoverall = OklahomaSt.overall;
    }else if(Tennessee.next == "PennSt"){
        opponentoverall = PennSt.overall;
    }else if(Tennessee.next == "Auburn"){
        opponentoverall = Auburn.overall;
    }else if(Tennessee.next == "UNC"){
        opponentoverall = UNC.overall;
    }else if(Tennessee.next == "MiamiFL"){
        opponentoverall = MiamiFL.overall;
    }else if(Tennessee.next == "OhioState"){
        opponentoverall = OhioState.overall;
    }
    cout << string( 100, '\n' );
    cout << "Year " << Year << endl;
    cout << "WEEK " << week << endl << endl;
    cout << "Team - " << Tennessee.name << endl;
    cout << "Team Overall - " << Tennessee.overall << endl;
    cout << "Record - " << "(" << Tennessee.win << "-" << Tennessee.loss << ")" << endl;
    cout << "Talent joining your team next year - " << addrat << endl;
    cout << "Next Game is " << Tennessee.next << endl;
    cout << "Opponent Overall - " << opponentoverall;
    cout << endl <<  "1- Play Next Game" << endl << "2- Teamboard" << endl << "3- Schedule" << endl << "4- Recruiting" << endl << "5- Customize" << endl;
    enum Choices{playgame = 1,teamboard, schedule, recruiting, customize};
        cin >> number;
        if(number == teamboard){
            goto TeamBoard;
            
        }else if(number == playgame){
            if(week < 9){
            goto week1;
        }else{
            goto Championship;
        }
        }else if(number == schedule){
            goto schedule;
        }else if(number == recruiting){
            if(tut == 0){
            
                cout << string( 100, '\n' );
                
            cout << "Do you want a recruiting tutorial?" << endl;
            cout << "1 - Yes" << endl << "2 - No" << endl;
            cin >> number;
            if(number == 2){
                tut = 1;
            goto recruiting;
            
        }else{
            tut = 1;
            goto rechelp;
        }
    }else{
        goto recruiting;
    }
        
        }else if(number == customize){
            goto customize;
        }   
rechelp:
        cout << string( 100, '\n' );
    cout << "Recruiting is simple! Scout players to find out how good they are, and call and offer visits to them to make them like your program more!" << endl << endl;
    cout << "It is recommended to start off by scouting!" << endl << "You can scout by typing in the corresponding number to that option, keep in mind this uses minutes, and you only have so much time in a day!" << endl;
    cout << "Now you will see a list of players! Type in one of their numbers to start scouting them." << endl << "At first, it will give you a basic range of their raiting, but the more you scout them, the more percise the raiting will become!" << endl << endl;
    cout << "You ready to call? Ok then, get to calling!" << endl << "Like before, type in the corresponding number to that option. Now you have the list of players again, all awaiting your call!" << endl;
    cout << "Pick one by typing in their number. Once you have done this, it will display how the call went, and how it effected their liking of your program!" << endl << "Sometime the call can go bad, and sometimes it can go great!" << endl;
    cout << "The more you call, the more their liking off your program goes higher!" << endl << "But keep in mind, this waists time, and you need to leave some time for the other players!" << endl << endl;
    cout << "Now, if you want, to boost their liking of your school, offer them to visit!" << endl << "If you win your football game the weekend they visit, then their liking goes up! Loose, and well, you get the point..." << endl << endl;
    cout << "Time to offer them that scholarship(As long as their liking is decently high!)! Depending on their liking of your program, they may or may not accept!" << endl << "If they accept, at the end of the year, their raiting will be added to your overall!" << endl;
    cin >> number;
    goto home;
    
customize:
    cout << "What is the new name for your team?" << endl;
    cin >> choice;
    Tennessee.name = choice;
    goto home;  
schedule:
    
    cout << string( 100, '\n' );
    cout << "Week 1 - " << Tennessee.week1 << endl << endl;
    cout << "Week 2 - " << Tennessee.week2 << endl << endl;
    cout << "Week 3 - " << Tennessee.week3 << endl << endl;
    cout << "Week 4 - " << Tennessee.week4 << endl << endl;
    cout << "Week 5 - " << Tennessee.week5 << endl << endl;
    cout << "Week 6 - " << Tennessee.week6 << endl << endl;
    cout << "Week 7 - " << Tennessee.week7 << endl << endl;
    cout << "Week 8 - " << Tennessee.week8 << endl << endl;
    cout << endl << "Type 1 and press Enter to continue." << endl;
    cin >> number;
    goto home;
        
recruiting:
        cout << string( 100, '\n' );
        cout << "How will you spend your minutes?" << endl;
        cout << "1 - Scout | 20 Minutes " << endl << "2- Call | 30 Minutes" << endl << "3- Offer Visit | 10 Minutes" << endl << "4- Offer Scholarship | 10 Minutes" << endl << "5- View Prospect Board" << endl << "6 - Back" << endl;
        cout << "Minutes remaining - " << minutes << endl;
        enum Choice{scout = 1, call, visit, scholarship, prospect, back};
        cin >> number;
            cout << "Prospect List shown below " << endl << endl;
        cout << "If Prospect Rating is 0, that means it is unknown. Prospect rating is out of ten..." << endl << endl;
    cout << "1 - " << prospect1 << " | " << oner << " | " << one << " | He likes your school  - " << onel << "%" << endl;
    cout << "2 - " << prospect2 << " | " << twor << " | " << two << " | He likes your school - " << two1 << "%" << endl;
    cout << "3 - " << prospect3 << " | " << threer << " | " << three << " | He likes your school - " << three1 << "%" << endl;
    cout << "4 - " << prospect4 << " | " << fourr << " | " << four << " | He likes your school - " << four1 << "%" << endl;
    cout << "5 - " << prospect5 << " | " << fiver << " | " << five << " | He likes your school - " << five1 << "%" << endl;
    cout << "6 - " << prospect6 << " | " << sixr << " | " << six << " | He likes your school - " << six1 << "%" << endl;
    cout << "7 - " << prospect7 << " | " << sevenr << " | " << seven << " | He likes your school - " << seven1 << "%" << endl;
    cout << "8 - " << prospect8 << " | " << eightr << " | " << eight << " | He likes your school - " << eight1 << "%" << endl;
    cout << "9 - " << prospect9 << " | " << niner << " | " << nine << " | He likes your school - " << nine1 << "%" << endl;
    cout << "10 - " << prospect10 << " | " << tenr << " | " << ten << " | He likes your school - " << ten1 << "%" << endl;
        if(number == 1){
            if(minutes > 19){
    
        cout << "Scout players to see their attributes, the more you scout, the more you know. Once you have scouted a player three times you have everything you need to know about him." << endl;
    cout << "Who would you like to scout today?" << endl;
    cin >> number;
    if(number == 1){
        if(one == " "){
            if(onec > 5){
            one = "Raiting is higher than five.";
            cout << "Raiting is higher than five." << endl;
             
        }else{
            one = "Raiting is five or lower.";
                cout << "Raiting is five or lower." << endl;
             
        }
        }else if(onet == 0){
            
            cout << "You almost know this player's exact raiting." << endl;
            onet = 1;
             
        }else{
            oner = onec;
            cout << "This player's raiting is " << oner << endl;
             
        }
    }else if(number == 2){
        if(two == " "){
            if(twoc > 5){
            two = "Raiting is higher than five.";
            cout << "Raiting is higher than five." << endl;
             
        }else{
            two = "Raiting is five or lower.";
                cout << "Raiting is five or lower." << endl;
             
        }
        }else if(twot == 0){
            
            cout << "You almost know this player's exact raiting." << endl;
            twot = 1;
             
        }else if(twot == 1){
            twor = twoc;
            cout << "This player's raiting is " << twor << endl;
             
        }
    }else if(number == 3){
        if(three == " "){
            if(threec > 5){
            three = "Raiting is higher than five.";
            cout << "Raiting is higher than five." << endl;
             
        }else{
            three = "Raiting is five or lower.";
                cout << "Raiting is five or lower." << endl;
             
        }
        }else if(threet == 0){
            
            cout << "You almost know this player's exact raiting." << endl;
                threet = 1;
             
        }else if(threet == 1){
            threer = threec;
            cout << "This player's raiting is " << threer << endl;
             
        }
    }else if(number == 4){
        if(four == " "){
            if(fourc > 5){
            four = "Raiting is higher than five.";
            cout << "Raiting is higher than five." << endl;
             
        }else{
            four = "Raiting is five or lower.";
                cout << "Raiting is five or lower." << endl;
             
        }
        }else if(fourt == 0){
            
            cout << "You almost know this player's exact raiting." << endl;
            fourt = 1;
             
        }else if(fourt == 1){
            fourr = fourc;
            cout << "This player's raiting is " << fourr << endl;
             
        }
    }else if(number == 5){
        if(five == " "){
            if(fivec > 5){
            five = "Raiting is higher than five.";
            cout << "Raiting is higher than five." << endl;
             
        }else{
            five = "Raiting is five or lower.";
                cout << "Raiting is five or lower." << endl;
             
        }
        }else if(fivet == 0){
            
            cout << "You almost know this player's exact raiting." << endl;
            fivet = 1;
             
        }else if(fivet == 1){
            fiver = fivec;
            cout << "This player's raiting is " << fiver << endl;
             
        }
    }else if(number == 6){
        if(six == " "){
            if(sixc > 5){
            six = "Raiting is higher than five.";
            cout << "Raiting is higher than five." << endl;
             
        }else{
            six = "Raiting is five or lower.";
                cout << "Raiting is five or lower." << endl;
             
        }
        }else if(sixt == 0){
            
            cout << "You almost know this player's exact raiting." << endl;
            sixt = 1;
             
        }else if(sixt == 1){
            sixr = sixc;
            cout << "This player's raiting is " << sixr << endl;
             
        }
    }else if(number == 7){
        if(seven == " "){
            if(sevenc > 5){
            seven = "Raiting is higher than five.";
            cout << "Raiting is higher than five." << endl;
             
        }else{
            seven = "Raiting is five or lower.";
                cout << "Raiting is five or lower." << endl;
             
        }
        }else if(sevent == 0){
            
            cout << "You almost know this player's exact raiting." << endl;
            sevent = 1;
             
        }else if(sevent == 1){
            sevenr = sevenc;
            cout << "This player's raiting is " << sevenr << endl;
             
        }
    }else if(number == 8){
        if(eight == " "){
            if(eightc > 5){
            eight = "Raiting is higher than five.";
            cout << "Raiting is higher than five." << endl;
             
        }else{
            eight = "Raiting is five or lower.";
                cout << "Raiting is five or lower." << endl;
             
        }
        }else if(eightt == 0){
            
            cout << "You almost know this player's exact raiting." << endl;
            eightt = 1;
             
        }else if(eightt == 1){
            eightr = eightc;
            cout << "This player's raiting is " << eightr << endl;
             
        }
    }else if(number == 9){
        if(nine == " "){
            if(ninec > 5){
            nine = "Raiting is higher than five.";
            cout << "Raiting is higher than five." << endl;
             
        }else{
            nine = "Raiting is five or lower.";
                cout << "Raiting is five or lower." << endl;
             
        }
        }else if(ninet == 0){
            
            cout << "You almost know this player's exact raiting." << endl;
            ninet = 1;
             
        }else if(ninet == 1){
            niner = ninec;
            cout << "This player's raiting is " << niner << endl;
             
        }
    }else if(number == 10){
    if(ten == " "){
            if(tenc > 5){
            ten = "Raiting is higher than five.";
            cout << "Raiting is higher than five." << endl;
             
            }else{
            ten = "Raiting is five or lower.";
            cout << "Raiting is five or lower." << endl;
             
            }
        }else if(tent == 0){
            
            cout << "You almost know this player's exact raiting." << endl;
            tent = 1;
             
        }else if(tent == 1){
            tenr = tenc;
            cout << "This player's raiting is " << tenr << endl;
             
        }
    }
    minutes = minutes - 20;

}else{
    cout << "You don't have enough minutes to do that action!" << endl;
     
}
}else if(number == call){
    if(minutes > 29){
    cout << "Who would you like to call today?" << endl;
    cin >> number;
    
        if(number == 1){
            random = 0;
            random = rand() % 15 + 1;
            if(random > 7){
                cout << "The call went great! This player likes you " << random << "% more!" << endl;
    
            
            }else{
                cout << "The player did not seem intrested in talking to you. The player only likes you " << random << "% more..." << endl;
                 
            }
            onel = onel + random;
        
    }else if(number == 2){


            random = 0;
            random = rand() % 15 + 1;
            if(random > 7){
                cout << "The call went great! This player likes you " << random << "% more!" << endl;
                 
            
            }else{
                cout << "The player did not seem intrested in talking to you. The player only likes you " << random << "% more..." << endl;
                 
            }
            two1 = two1 + random;
        
    }else if(number == 3){
    
            random = 0;
            random = rand() % 15 + 1;
            if(random > 7){
                cout << "The call went great! This player likes you " << random << "% more!" << endl;
                 
            
            }else{
                cout << "The player did not seem intrested in talking to you. The player only likes you " << random << "% more..." << endl;
                 
            }
            three1 = three1 + random;

    }else if(number == 4){

            random = 0;
            random = rand() % 15 + 1;
            if(random > 7){
                cout << "The call went great! This player likes you " << random << "% more!" << endl;
                 
            
            }else{
                cout << "The player did not seem intrested in talking to you. The player only likes you " << random << "% more..." << endl;
                 
            }
            four1 = four1 + random;
         
    }else if(number == 5){
        
            random = 0;
            random = rand() % 15 + 1;
            if(random > 7){
                cout << "The call went great! This player likes you " << random << "% more!" << endl;
                 
            
            }else{
                cout << "The player did not seem intrested in talking to you. The player only likes you " << random << "% more..." << endl;
                 
            }
            five1 = five1 + random;
        
    }else if(number == 6){
    
            random = 0;
            random = rand() % 15 + 1;
            if(random > 7){
                cout << "The call went great! This player likes you " << random << "% more!" << endl;
                 
            
            }else{
                cout << "The player did not seem intrested in talking to you. The player only likes you " << random << "% more..." << endl;
                 
            }
        six1 = six1 + random;
        
    }else if(number == 7){
        
            random = 0;
            random = rand() % 15 + 1;
            if(random > 7){
                cout << "The call went great! This player likes you " << random << "% more!" << endl;
                 
            
            }else{
                cout << "The player did not seem intrested in talking to you. The player only likes you " << random << "% more..." << endl;
                 
            }
            seven1 = seven1 + random;
         
    }else if(number == 8){
        
            random = 0;
            random = rand() % 15 + 1;
            if(random > 7){
                cout << "The call went great! This player likes you " << random << "% more!" << endl;
                 
            
            }else{
                cout << "The player did not seem intrested in talking to you. The player only likes you " << random << "% more..." << endl;
                 
            }
            eight1 = eight1 + random;
        
    }else if(number == 9){
        
            random = 0;
            random = rand() % 15 + 1;
            if(random > 7){
                cout << "The call went great! This player likes you " << random << "% more!" << endl;
                 
            
            }else{
                cout << "The player did not seem intrested in talking to you. The player only likes you " << random << "% more..." << endl;
                 
            }
            nine1 = nine1 + random;
      
    }else if(number == 10){
        
            random = 0;
            random = rand() % 15 + 1;
            if(random > 7){
                cout << "The call went great! This player likes you " << random << "% more!" << endl;
                 
            
            }else{
                cout << "The player did not seem intrested in talking to you. The player only likes you " << random << "% more..." << endl;
                 
            }
            ten1 = ten1 + random;
        
    }
        minutes = minutes - 30;
}else{
    cout << "You don't have enough minutes to complete this action!" << endl;
        

}


}else if(number == visit){
    if(minutes > 9){
        minutes = minutes - 10;
        cout << "Who would you liked to offer a visit coach?" << endl;
        cin >> number;
        if(number == 1){
            random = 0;
            random = rand() % 50 + 1;
            if(onel > random){
                cout << "I'd be delighted to visit!";
                onev = 1;
            }else if(onel <= random){
                cout << "I haven't really considered your program, coach." << endl;
            }
        }else if(number == 2){
            random = 0;
            random = rand() % 50 + 1;
            if(two1 > random){
                cout << "I'd be delighted to visit!";
                twov = 1;
            }else if(two1 <= random){
                cout << "I haven't really considered your program, coach." << endl;
            }
        }else if(number == 3){
            random = 0;
            random = rand() % 50 + 1;
            if(three1 > random){
                cout << "I'd be delighted to visit!";
                threev = 1;
            }else if(three1 <= random){
                cout << "I haven't really considered your program, coach." << endl;
            }
        }else if(number == 4){
            random = 0;
            random = rand() % 50 + 1;
            if(four1 > random){
                cout << "I'd be delighted to visit!";
                fourv = 1;
            }else if(four1 <= random){
                cout << "I haven't really considered your program, coach." << endl;
            }
            }else if(number == 5){
            random = 0;
            random = rand() % 50 + 1;
            if(five1 > random){
                cout << "I'd be delighted to visit!";
                fivev = 1;
            }else if(five1 <= random){
                cout << "I haven't really considered your program, coach." << endl;
            }
            }else if(number == 6){
            random = 0;
            random = rand() % 50 + 1;
            if(six1 > random){
                cout << "I'd be delighted to visit!";
                sixv = 1;
            }else if(six1 <= random){
                cout << "I haven't really considered your program, coach." << endl;
            }
            }else if(number == 7){
            random = 0;
            random = rand() % 50 + 1;
            if(seven1 > random){
                cout << "I'd be delighted to visit!";
                sevenv = 1;
            }else if(seven1 <= random){
                cout << "I haven't really considered your program, coach." << endl;
            }
            }else if(number == 8){
            random = 0;
            random = rand() % 50 + 1;
            if(eight1 > random){
                cout << "I'd be delighted to visit!";
                eightv = 1;
            }else if(eight1 <= random){
                cout << "I haven't really considered your program, coach." << endl;
            }
            }else if(number == 9){
            random = 0;
            random = rand() % 50 + 1;
            if(nine1 > random){
                cout << "I'd be delighted to visit!";
                ninev = 1;
            }else if(nine1 <= random){
                cout << "I haven't really considered your program, coach." << endl;
            }
        }else if(number == 10){
            random = 0;
            random = rand() % 50 + 1;
            if(ten1 > random){
                cout << "I'd be delighted to visit!";
                tenv = 1;
            }else if(ten1 <= random){
                cout << "I haven't really considered your program, coach." << endl;
            }
        }
        }else{
        cout << "You don't have enough minutes to complete this action..." << endl;
    
    }
    
    }else if(number == scholarship){
        if(minutes > 9){
            minutes = minutes - 10;
        
        cout << "Who will you offer a scholarship coach?" << endl;
        cin >> number;
        if(number == 1){
            
            if(ones == 0){
            ones = 1;
            rands = 0;
            rands = rand() % 150 + 1;
            if(onel > rands){
                cout << "I'd be glad to join your program!" << endl;
                addrat = addrat + twoc;
            }else{
                cout << "Sorry coach, but I don't think your school would fit my playstyle" << endl;
            }
        }else{
            cout << "You've already offered him a scholarship!" << endl;
        }
        }else if(number == 2){
            if(twos == 0){
            twos = 1;
            rands = 0;
            rands = rand() % 150 + 1;
            if(two1 > rands){
                cout << "I'd be glad to join your program!" << endl;
                addrat = addrat + onec;
            }else{
                cout << "Sorry coach, but I don't think your school would fit my playstyle" << endl;
            }
        }else{
            cout << "You've already offered him a scholarship!" << endl;
        }
        }else if(number == 3){
            if(threes == 0){
            threes = 1;
            rands = 0;
            rands = rand() % 150 + 1;
            if(three1 > rands){
                cout << "I'd be glad to join your program!" << endl;
                addrat = addrat + threec;
            }else{
                cout << "Sorry coach, but I don't think your school would fit my playstyle" << endl;
            }
        }else{
            cout << "You've already offered him a scholarship!" << endl;
        }
        }else if(number == 4){
            if(fours == 0){
            fours = 1;
            rands = 0;
            rands = rand() % 150 + 1;
            if(four1 > rands){
                cout << "I'd be glad to join your program!" << endl;
                addrat = addrat + fourc;
            }else{
                cout << "Sorry coach, but I don't think your school would fit my playstyle" << endl;
            }
        }else{
            cout << "You've already offered him a scholarship!" << endl;
        }
        }else if(number == 5){
            if(fives == 0){
            fives = 1;
            rands = 0;
            rands = rand() % 150 + 1;
            if(five1 > rands){
                cout << "I'd be glad to join your program!" << endl;
                addrat = addrat + fivec;
            }else{
                cout << "Sorry coach, but I don't think your school would fit my playstyle" << endl;
            }
        }else{
            cout << "You've already offered him a scholarship!" << endl;
        }
        }else if(number == 6){
            if(sixs == 0){
            sixs = 1;
            rands = 0;
            rands = rand() % 150 + 1;
            if(six1 > rands){
                cout << "I'd be glad to join your program!" << endl;
                addrat = addrat + sixc;
            }else{
                cout << "Sorry coach, but I don't think your school would fit my playstyle" << endl;
            }
        }else{
            cout << "You've already offered him a scholarship!" << endl;
        }
        }else if(number == 7){
            if(sevens == 0){
            sevens = 1;
            rands = 0;
            rands = rand() % 150 + 1;
            if(seven1 > rands){
                cout << "I'd be glad to join your program!" << endl;
                addrat = addrat + sevenc;
            }else{
                cout << "Sorry coach, but I don't think your school would fit my playstyle" << endl;
            }
        }else{
            cout << "You've already offered him a scholarship!" << endl;
        }
        }else if(number == 8){
            if(eights == 0){
            eights = 1;
            rands = 0;
            rands = rand() % 150 + 1;
            if(eight1 > rands){
                cout << "I'd be glad to join your program!" << endl;
                addrat = addrat + eightc;
            }else{
                cout << "Sorry coach, but I don't think your school would fit my playstyle" << endl;
            }
        }else{
            cout << "You've already offered him a scholarship!" << endl;
        }
        }else if(number == 9){
            if(nines == 0){
            nines = 1;
            rands = 0;
            rands = rand() % 150 + 1;
            if(nine1 > rands){
                cout << "I'd be glad to join your program!" << endl;
                addrat = addrat + ninec;
            }else{
                cout << "Sorry coach, but I don't think your school would fit my playstyle" << endl;
            }
        }else{
            cout << "You've already offered him a scholarship!" << endl;
        }
        }else if(number == 10){
            if(tens == 0){
            tens = 1;
            rands = 0;
            rands = rand() % 150 + 1;
            if(ten1 > rands){
                cout << "I'd be glad to join your program!" << endl;
                addrat = addrat + tenc;
            }else{
                cout << "Sorry coach, but I don't think your school would fit my playstyle" << endl;
            }
        }else{
            cout << "You've already offered him a scholarship!" << endl;
        }
        }
    }else{
        cout << "You don't have enough minutes to do this action!" << endl;
    }
}else if(number == prospect){
    cout << "Here are the prospects!" << endl;
    
}else if(number == back){
    goto home;
    
}


    cin >> number;          



    goto home;
    
week1:

    if(week < 9){
    
    if(Georgia.name !=  Tennessee.next){
        random5 = rand() % 100 + 1;
        if(Georgia.overall > random5){
            Georgia.win = Georgia.win + 1;
            Georgia.overall = Georgia.overall + 1;
        }else {
            Georgia.loss = Georgia.loss + 1;
            Georgia.overall = Georgia.overall - 1;
        }
    }
    random5 = 0;
    if(Alabama.name !=  Tennessee.next){
        random5 = rand() % 100 + 1;
        if(Alabama.overall > random5){
            Alabama.win = Alabama.win + 1;
            Alabama.overall = Alabama.overall + 1;
        }else {
            Alabama.loss = Alabama.loss + 1;
            Alabama.overall = Alabama.overall - 1;
        }
    }
    random5 = 0;
        if(Clemson.name !=  Tennessee.next){
        random5 = rand() % 100 + 1;
        if(Clemson.overall > random5){
            Clemson.win = Clemson.win + 1;
            Clemson.overall = Clemson.overall + 1;
        }else {
            Clemson.loss = Clemson.loss + 1;
            Clemson.overall = Clemson.overall - 1;
        }
    }
    random5 = 0;
if(MiamiFL.name !=  Tennessee.next){
        random5 = rand() % 100 + 1;
        if(MiamiFL.overall > random5){
            MiamiFL.win = MiamiFL.win + 1;
            MiamiFL.overall = MiamiFL.overall + 1;
        }else {
            MiamiFL.loss = MiamiFL.loss + 1;
            MiamiFL.overall = MiamiFL.overall - 1;
        }
    }
    random5 = 0;
    if(Auburn.name !=  Tennessee.next){
        random5 = rand() % 100 + 1;
        if(Auburn.overall > random5){
            Auburn.win = Auburn.win + 1;
            Auburn.overall = Auburn.overall + 1;
        }else {
            Auburn.loss = Auburn.loss + 1;
            Auburn.overall = Auburn.overall - 1;
        }
    }   
    random5 = 0;
        if(OhioState.name !=  Tennessee.next){
        random5 = rand() % 100 + 1;
        if(OhioState.overall > random5){
            OhioState.win = OhioState.win + 1;
            OhioState.overall = OhioState.overall + 1;
        }else {
            OhioState.loss = OhioState.loss + 1;
            OhioState.overall = OhioState.overall - 1;
        }
    }
    random5 = 0;
        if(OklahomaSt.name !=  Tennessee.next){
        random5 = rand() % 100 + 1;
        if(OklahomaSt.overall > random5){
            OklahomaSt.win = OklahomaSt.win + 1;
            OklahomaSt.overall = OklahomaSt.overall + 1;
        }else {
            OklahomaSt.loss = OklahomaSt.loss + 1;
            OklahomaSt.overall = OklahomaSt.overall - 1;
        }
    }
    random5 = 0;
if(Tennessee.next == "Championship"){
    goto Championship;
}
        if(NotreDame.name !=  Tennessee.next){
        random5 = rand() % 100 + 1;
        if(NotreDame.overall > random5){
            NotreDame.win = NotreDame.win + 1;
            NotreDame.overall = NotreDame.overall + 1;
        }else {
            NotreDame.loss = NotreDame.loss + 1;
            NotreDame.overall = NotreDame.overall - 1;
        }
    }   
    random5 = 0;
    if(UNC.name !=  Tennessee.next){
        random5 = rand() % 100 + 1;
        if(UNC.overall > random5){
            UNC.win = UNC.win + 1;
            UNC.overall = UNC.overall + 1;
        }else {
            UNC.loss = UNC.loss + 1;
            UNC.overall = UNC.overall - 1;
        }
    }
    random5 = 0;
    if(PennSt.name !=  Tennessee.next){
        random5 = rand() % 100 + 1;
        if(PennSt.overall > random5){
            PennSt.win = PennSt.win + 1;
            PennSt.overall = PennSt.overall + 1;
        }else {
            PennSt.loss = PennSt.loss + 1;
            PennSt.overall = PennSt.overall - 1;
        }
    }
    random5 = 0;
    if(Florida.name !=  Tennessee.next){
        random5 = rand() % 100 + 1;
        if(Florida.overall > random5){
            Florida.win = Florida.win + 1;
            Florida.overall = Florida.overall + 1;
        }else {
            Florida.loss = Florida.loss + 1;
            Florida.overall = Florida.overall - 1;
        }
    }
    random5 = 0;
}
    
        
    cout << string( 100, '\n' );;
    score = opponentoverall * 0.35;
random = rand() % 15 + -5;
random2 = rand() % 15 + -5;
random = random - random2;
score = score + random;
score2 = Tennessee.overall * 0.35;
random3 = rand() % 15 + -5;
random4 = rand() % 15 + -5;
random3 = random4 - random3;
        score2 = score2 + random3;
if(score < 2){
    score = 0;
}
if(score2 < 2){
    score2 = 0;
}

cout << Tennessee.name << " scored " << score2 << " | " << Tennessee.next << " scored " << score << endl;
     if(score2 > score){
        cout << "You won! Your overall has increased three points!" << endl;
        Tennessee.win = Tennessee.win + 1;
        Tennessee.overall = Tennessee.overall + 3;
        randoml = 0;
if(onev == 1){
    randoml = 0;
    randoml = rand() % 20 + 1;
    onel = onel + randoml;
    cout << "You had a recruit visiting and you won! The recruit's liking of your school has increased by " << randoml << endl;
    onev = 0;
}
if(twov == 1){
    randoml = 0;
    randoml = rand() % 20 + 1;
    two1 = two1 + randoml;
    cout << "You had a recruit visiting and you won! The recruit's liking of your school has increased by " << randoml << endl;
    twov = 0;
}
if(threev == 1){
    randoml = 0;
    randoml = rand() % 20 + 1;
    three1 = three1 + randoml;
    cout << "You had a recruit visiting and you won! The recruit's liking of your school has increased by " << randoml << endl;
    threev = 0;
}
if(fourv == 1){
    randoml = 0;
    randoml = rand() % 20 + 1;
    four1 = four1 + randoml;
    cout << "You had a recruit visiting and you won! The recruit's liking of your school has increased by " << randoml << endl;
    fourv = 0;
}
if(fivev == 1){
    randoml = 0;
    randoml = rand() % 20 + 1;
    five1 = five1 + randoml;
    cout << "You had a recruit visiting and you won! The recruit's liking of your school has increased by " << randoml << endl;
    fivev = 0;
}
if(sixv == 1){
    randoml = 0;
    randoml = rand() % 20 + 1;
    six1 = six1 + randoml;
    cout << "You had a recruit visiting and you won! The recruit's liking of your school has increased by " << randoml << endl;
    sixv = 0;
}
if(sevenv == 1){
    randoml = 0;
    randoml = rand() % 20 + 1;
    seven1 = seven1 + randoml;
    cout << "You had a recruit visiting and you won! The recruit's liking of your school has increased by " << randoml << endl;
    sevenv = 0;
}
if(eightv == 1){
    randoml = 0;
    randoml = rand() % 20 + 1;
    eight1 = eight1 + randoml;
    cout << "You had a recruit visiting and you won! The recruit's liking of your school has increased by " << randoml << endl;
    eightv = 0;
}
if(ninev == 1){
    randoml = 0;
    randoml = rand() % 20 + 1;
    nine1 = nine1 + randoml;
    cout << "You had a recruit visiting and you won! The recruit's liking of your school has increased by " << randoml << endl;
    ninev = 0;
}
if(tenv == 1){
    randoml = 0;
    randoml = rand() % 20 + 1;
    ten1 = ten1 + randoml;
    cout << "You had a recruit visiting and you won! The recruit's liking of your school has increased by " << randoml << endl;
    tenv = 0;
}
        
        if(Tennessee.next == "Georgia"){
        Georgia.loss = Georgia.loss + 1;
        Georgia.overall = Georgia.overall - 1;
    }else if(Tennessee.next == "Alabama"){
        Alabama.loss = Alabama.loss + 1;
        Alabama.overall = Alabama.overall - 1;
    }else if(Tennessee.next == "Oklahoma State"){
        OklahomaSt.loss = OklahomaSt.loss + 1;
        OklahomaSt.overall = OklahomaSt.overall - 1;
    }else if(Tennessee.next == "Penn State"){
        PennSt.loss = PennSt.loss + 1;
        PennSt.overall = PennSt.overall - 1;
    }else if(Tennessee.next == "Auburn"){
        Auburn.loss = Auburn.loss + 1;
        Auburn.overall = Auburn.overall - 1;
    }else if(Tennessee.next == "UNC"){
          UNC.loss = UNC.loss + 1;
          UNC.overall = UNC.overall - 1;
    }else if(Tennessee.next == "Miami FL"){
        MiamiFL.loss = MiamiFL.loss + 1;
        MiamiFL.overall = MiamiFL.overall - 1;
    }else if(Tennessee.next == "Ohio State"){
        OhioState.loss = OhioState.loss + 1;
        OhioState.overall = OhioState.overall - 1;
    }
     }else if(score > score2){
        cout << "You lost... Your overall has decreased three points..." << endl;
        Tennessee.loss = Tennessee.loss + 1;
        Tennessee.overall = Tennessee.overall - 3;
        if(onev == 1){
    randoml = rand() % 15 + 1;
    onel = onel - randoml;
    cout << "You had a recruit visiting and you lost... The recruit's liking of your school has decreased by " << randoml << endl;
}
if(twov == 1){
    randoml = 0;
    randoml = rand() % 15 + 1;
    two1 = two1 - randoml;
    cout << "You had a recruit visiting and you lost... The recruit's liking of your school has decreased by " << randoml << endl;
    twov = 0;
}
if(threev == 1){
    randoml = 0;
    randoml = rand() % 15 + 1;
    three1 = three1 - randoml;
    cout << "You had a recruit visiting and you lost... The recruit's liking of your school has decreased by " << randoml << endl;
    threev = 0;
}
if(fourv == 1){
    randoml = 0;
    randoml = rand() % 15 + 1;
    four1 = four1 - randoml;
    cout << "You had a recruit visiting and you lost... The recruit's liking of your school has decreased by " << randoml << endl;
    fourv = 0;
}
if(fivev == 1){
    randoml = 0;
    randoml = rand() % 15 + 1;
    five1 = five1 - randoml;
    cout << "You had a recruit visiting and you lost... The recruit's liking of your school has decreased by " << randoml << endl;
    fivev = 0;
}
if(sixv == 1){
    randoml = 0;
    randoml = rand() % 15 + 1;
    six1 = six1 - randoml;
    cout << "You had a recruit visiting and you lost... The recruit's liking of your school has decreased by " << randoml << endl;
    sixv = 0;
}
if(sevenv == 1){
    randoml = 0;
    randoml = rand() % 15 + 1;
    seven1 = seven1 - randoml;
    cout << "You had a recruit visiting and you lost... The recruit's liking of your school has decreased by " << randoml << endl;
    sevenv = 0;
}
if(eightv == 1){
    randoml = 0;
    randoml = rand() % 15 + 1;
    eight1 = eight1 - randoml;
    cout << "You had a recruit visiting and you lost... The recruit's liking of your school has decreased by " << randoml << endl;
    eightv = 0;
}
if(ninev == 1){
    randoml = 0;
    randoml = rand() % 15 + 1;
    nine1 = nine1 - randoml;
    cout << "You had a recruit visiting and you lost... The recruit's liking of your school has decreased by " << randoml << endl;
    ninev = 0;
}
if(tenv == 1){
    randoml = 0;
    randoml = rand() % 15 + 1;
    ten1 = ten1 - randoml;
    cout << "You had a recruit visiting and you lost... The recruit's liking of your school has decreased by " << randoml << endl;
    tenv = 0;
}
        
        
            if(Tennessee.next == "Georgia"){
        Georgia.win = Georgia.win + 1;
        Georgia.overall = Georgia.overall + 1;
    }else if(Tennessee.next == "Alabama"){
        Alabama.win = Alabama.win + 1;
        Alabama.overall = Alabama.overall + 1;
    }else if(Tennessee.next == "Oklahoma State"){
        OklahomaSt.win = OklahomaSt.win + 1;
        OklahomaSt.overall = OklahomaSt.overall + 1;
    }else if(Tennessee.next == "Penn State"){
        PennSt.win = PennSt.win + 1;
        PennSt.overall = PennSt.overall + 1;
    }else if(Tennessee.next == "Auburn"){
        Auburn.win = Auburn.win + 1;
        Auburn.overall = Auburn.overall + 1;
    }else if(Tennessee.next == "UNC"){
          UNC.win = UNC.win + 1;
          UNC.overall = UNC.overall + 1;
    }else if(Tennessee.next == "Miami FL"){
        MiamiFL.win = MiamiFL.win + 1;
        MiamiFL.overall = MiamiFL.overall + 1;
    }else if(Tennessee.next == "Ohio State"){
        OhioState.win = OhioState.win + 1;
        OhioState.overall = OhioState.overall + 1;
    }else if(Tennessee.next == "Championship"){
        goto Championship;
        minutes = 60;
    }
        
     }else{
        goto week1;
     }
     if(week == 1){
     
        week = 2;
        minutes = 120;
        Tennessee.next = Tennessee.week2;
     }else if(week == 2){
     
        week = 3;
        minutes = 120;
        Tennessee.next = Tennessee.week3;
     }else if(week == 3){
     
        week = 4;
        minutes = 120;
        Tennessee.next = Tennessee.week4;
     }else if(week == 4){
     
        week = 5;
        minutes = 120;
        Tennessee.next = Tennessee.week5;
     }else if(week == 5){
        week = 6;
        minutes = 120;
        Tennessee.next = Tennessee.week6;
     }else if(week == 6){
        week = 7;
        minutes = 120;
        Tennessee.next = Tennessee.week7;
     }else if(week == 7){
        week = 8;
        minutes = 120;
        Tennessee.next = Tennessee.week8;
     }else if(week == 8){
        week = 9;
        minutes = 0;
        Tennessee.next = "Championship";
     }
     cout << endl << "Type 1 and press Enter to continue..." << endl;
    cin >> number;
    goto home;
    
Championship:
        cout << string( 100, '\n' );
    cout << OhioState.name << " | Overall - " << OhioState.overall << " ( " << OhioState.win << " - " << OhioState.loss << " ) " << endl << endl;
    cout << Alabama.name << " | Overall - " << Alabama.overall << " ( " << Alabama.win << " - " << Alabama.loss << " ) " << endl << endl;
    cout << MiamiFL.name << " | Overall - " << MiamiFL.overall << " ( " << MiamiFL.win << " - " << MiamiFL.loss << " ) " << endl << endl;
    cout << OklahomaSt.name << " | Overall - " << OklahomaSt.overall << " ( " << OklahomaSt.win << " - " << OklahomaSt.loss << " ) " << endl << endl;
    cout << Auburn.name << " | Overall - " << Auburn.overall << " ( " << Auburn.win << " - " << Auburn.loss << " ) " << endl << endl;
    cout << Tennessee.name << " | Overall - " << Tennessee.overall << " ( " << Tennessee.win << " - " << Tennessee.loss << " ) " << endl << endl;
    cout << PennSt.name << " | Overall - " << PennSt.overall << " ( " << PennSt.win << " - " << PennSt.loss << " ) " << endl << endl;
    cout << Florida.name << " | Overall - " << Florida.overall << " ( " << Florida.win << " - " << Florida.loss << " ) " << endl << endl;
    cout << Georgia.name << " | Overall - " << Georgia.overall << " ( " << Georgia.win << " - " << Georgia.loss << " ) " << endl << endl;
    cout << UNC.name << " | Overall - " << UNC.overall << " ( " << UNC.win << " - " << UNC.loss << " ) " << endl << endl;
    cout << NotreDame.name << " | Overall - " << NotreDame.overall << " ( " << NotreDame.win << " - " << NotreDame.loss << " ) " << endl << endl;
        cout << Clemson.name << " | Overall - " << Clemson.overall << " ( " << Clemson.win << " - " << Clemson.loss << " ) " << endl << endl;
    
    cout << "Welcome to the Championship! Answer this : Did your team do the best this year? Tie goes to highest overall!" << endl;
    cout << "1 - Yes" << endl << "2- No" << endl;
    cin >> number;
        if(number == 1) {
            champ1 = Tennessee.overall;
            champname = "Tennessee";
        }else{
            cout << "Ok the, who did the best?" << endl;
            cout << "1 -  Clemson" << endl << "2 - Alabama " << endl << "3 - Florida" << endl << "4 - Georgia" << endl << "5 - MiamiFL" << endl << "6 - Oklahoma State" << endl;
            cout << "7 - Auburn" << endl << "8 - UNC" << endl << "9 - Notre Dame" << endl << "10 - Penn State" << endl << "11 - Ohio State?" << endl;
                 cin >> number;
                 if(number == 1){
            champ1 = Clemson.overall;
            champname = "Clemson";
            Clemson.overall = Clemson.overall + 6;
         }else if(number == 2){
            champ1 = Alabama.overall;
            champname = "Alabama";
            Alabama.overall = Alabama.overall + 6;
         }else if(number == 3){
            champ1 = Florida.overall;
            champname = "Florida";
            Florida.overall = Florida.overall + 6;
         }else if(number == 4){
            champ1 = Georgia.overall;
            champname = "Georgia";
            Georgia.overall = Georgia.overall + 6;
         }else if(number == 5){
            champ1 = MiamiFL.overall;
            champname = "Miami FL";
            MiamiFL.overall = MiamiFL.overall + 6;
         }else if(number == 6){
            champ1 = OklahomaSt.overall;
            champname = "OklahomaST";
            OklahomaSt.overall = OklahomaSt.overall + 6;
         }else if(number == 7){
            champ1 = Auburn.overall;
            champname = "Auburn";
            Auburn.overall = Auburn.overall + 6;
         }else if(number == 8){
            champ1 = UNC.overall;
            champname = "UNC";
            UNC.overall = UNC.overall + 6;
         }else if(number == 9){
            champ1 = NotreDame.overall;
            champname = "Notre Dame";
            NotreDame.overall = NotreDame.overall + 6;
         }else if(number == 10){
            champ1 = PennSt.overall;
            champname = "Penn State";
            PennSt.overall = PennSt.overall + 6;
         }else if(number == 11){
            champ1 = OhioState.overall;
            champname = "Ohio State";
            OhioState.overall = OhioState.overall + 6;
         }
            }
            cout << "Did your team do the second best this year?" << endl;
                cout << "1 - Yes" << endl << "2- No" << endl;
            cin >> number;
            if(number == 1){
                champ2 = Tennessee.overall;
                champname = "Tennessee";
            }else{
        cout << "Which of these teams did the second best?" << endl;
        cout << "1 -  Clemson" << endl << "2 - Alabama " << endl << "3 - Florida" << endl << "4 - Georgia" << endl << "5 - MiamiFL" << endl << "6 - Oklahoma State" << endl;
            cout << "7 - Auburn" << endl << "8 - UNC" << endl << "9 - Notre Dame" << endl << "10 - Penn State" << endl << "11 - Ohio State?" << endl;
        cin >> number;
        if(number == 1){
            champ2 = Clemson.overall;
            champname2 = "Clemson";
            Clemson.overall = Clemson.overall + 3;
         }else if(number == 2){
            champ2 = Alabama.overall;
            champname2 = "Alabama";
                Alabama.overall = Alabama.overall + 3;
         }else if(number == 3){
            champ2 = Florida.overall;
            champname2 = "Florida";
                Florida.overall = Florida.overall + 3;
         }else if(number == 4){
            champ2 = Georgia.overall;
            champname2 = "Georgia";
                Georgia.overall = Georgia.overall + 3;
         }else if(number == 5){
            champ2 = MiamiFL.overall;
            champname2 = "Miami FL";
                MiamiFL.overall = MiamiFL.overall + 3;
         }else if(number == 6){
            champ2 = OklahomaSt.overall;
            champname2 = "OklahomaST";
                OklahomaSt.overall = OklahomaSt.overall + 3;
         }else if(number == 7){
            champ2 = Auburn.overall;
            champname2 = "Auburn";
                Auburn.overall = Auburn.overall + 3;
         }else if(number == 8){
            champ2 = UNC.overall;
            champname2 = "UNC";
                UNC.overall = UNC.overall + 3;
         }else if(number == 9){
            champ2 = NotreDame.overall;
            champname2 = "Notre Dame";
                NotreDame.overall = NotreDame.overall + 3;
         }else if(number == 10){
            champ2 = PennSt.overall;
            champname2 = "Penn State";
                PennSt.overall = PennSt.overall + 3;
         }else if(number == 11){
            champ2 = OhioState.overall;
            champname2 = "Ohio State";
                OhioState.overall = OhioState.overall + 3;
         }
calc:
        score = champ1 * 0.5;
random = rand() % 5 + -20;
random2 = rand() % 20 + -5;
random = random + random2;
score = score + random;
score2 = champ2 * 0.5;;
random3 = rand() % 5 + -20;
random4 = rand() % 20 + -5;
random3 = random3 + random4;
        score2 = score2 + random3;
if(score < 2){
    score = 0;
}
if(score2 < 2){
    score2 = 0;
}
if(score == score2){
    goto calc;
}
cout << champname2 << " scored " << score2 << " | " << champname << " scored " << score << endl;
         cin >> number;
week = 1;


random3 = 0;
random3 = rand() % 5 + -10;
random4 = rand() % 10 + -5;
random3 = random3 + random4;
Alabama.overall = Alabama.overall + random3;
random3 = 0;
random3 = rand() % 5 + -10;
random4 = rand() % 10 + -5;
random3 = random3 + random4;
Clemson.overall = Clemson.overall + random3;
random3 = 0;
random3 = rand() % 5 + -10;
random4 = rand() % 10 + -5;
random3 = random3 + random4;
UNC.overall = UNC.overall + random3;
random3 = 0;
random3 = rand() % 5 + -10;
random4 = rand() % 10 + -5;
random3 = random3 + random4;
OklahomaSt.overall = OklahomaSt.overall + random3;
random3 = 0;
random3 = rand() % 5 + -10;
random4 = rand() % 10 + -5;
random3 = random3 + random4;
PennSt.overall = PennSt.overall + random3;
random3 = 0;
random3 = rand() % 5 + -10;
random4 = rand() % 10 + -5;
random3 = random3 + random4;
OhioState.overall = OhioState.overall + random3;
random3 = 0;
random3 = rand() % 5 + -10;
random4 = rand() % 10 + -5;
random3 = random3 + random4;
Auburn.overall = Auburn.overall + random3;
random3 = 0;
random3 = rand() % 5 + -10;
random4 = rand() % 10 + -5;
random3 = random3 + random4;
Georgia.overall = Georgia.overall + random3;
random3 = 0;
random3 = rand() % 5 + -10;
random4 = rand() % 10 + -5;
random3 = random3 + random4;
Florida.overall = Florida.overall + random3;
random3 = 0;
random3 = rand() % 5 + -10;
random4 = rand() % 10 + -5;
random3 = random3 + random4;
MiamiFL.overall = MiamiFL.overall + random3;
random3 = 0;
random3 = rand() % 5 + -10;
random4 = rand() % 10 + -5;
random3 = random3 + random4;
NotreDame.overall = NotreDame.overall + random3;
random3 = 0;

Tennessee.next = Tennessee.week1;

Year = Year + 1;

NotreDame.win = 0;
NotreDame.loss = 0;
 
 UNC.win = 0;
UNC.loss = 0;
 
 Florida.win = 0;
Florida.loss = 0;
 
 PennSt.win = 0;
PennSt.loss = 0;
 
 OklahomaSt.win = 0;
OklahomaSt.loss = 0;
 
 OhioState.win = 0;
OhioState.loss = 0;
 
 Auburn.win = 0;
Auburn.loss = 0;
 
 MiamiFL.win = 0;
MiamiFL.loss = 0;
 
 Clemson.win = 0;
Clemson.loss = 0;
 
 Alabama.win = 0;
Alabama.loss = 0;
 
 MiamiFL.win = 0;
MiamiFL.loss = 0;
 
 Tennessee.win = 0;
Tennessee.loss = 0;

  one = " ";
  two = " ";
  three = " ";
  four = " ";
  five = " ";
  six = " ";
  seven = " ";
  eight = " ";
  nine = " ";
  ten = " ";
  
    oner = 0;
  twor = 0;
  threer = 0;
  fourr = 0;
  fiver = 0;
  sixr = 0;
  sevenr = 0;
  eightr = 0;
  niner = 0;
  tenr = 0;
  ones = 0;
  twos = 0;
  threes = 0;
  fours = 0;
  fives = 0;
  sixs = 0;
  sevens = 0;
  eights = 0;
  nines = 0;
  tens = 0;
  
    onet = 0;
  twot = 0;
  threet = 0;
  fourt = 0;
  fivet = 0;
  sixt = 0;
  sevent = 0;
  eightt = 0;
  ninet = 0;
  tent = 0;
  
  minutes = 120;
  
  Tennessee.overall = Tennessee.overall + addrat;
  
    onel = rand() % 30 + 1;
  two1 = rand() % 30 + 1;
  three1 = rand() % 30 + 1;
  four1 = rand() % 30 + 1;
  five1 = rand() % 30 + 1;
  six1 = rand() % 30 + 1;
  seven1 = rand() % 30 + 1;
  eight1 = rand() % 30 + 1;
  nine1 = rand() % 30 + 1;
  ten1 = rand() % 30 + 1;
  onec = rand() % 10 + 1;
  twoc = rand() % 10 + 1;
  threec = rand() % 10 + 1;
  fourc = rand() % 10 + 1;
  fivec = rand() % 10 + 1;
  sixc = rand() % 10 + 1;
  sevenc = rand() % 10 + 1;
  eightc = rand() % 10 + 1;
  ninec = rand() % 10 + 1;
  tenc = rand() % 10 + 1;

addrat = 0;

goto home;
 
 

}
    
TeamBoard:
    cout << string( 100, '\n' );
    cout << "Team Board - All Teams and their Stats - Teams are not sorted" << endl << endl;
    cout << OhioState.name << " | Overall - " << OhioState.overall << " ( " << OhioState.win << " - " << OhioState.loss << " ) " << endl << endl;
    cout << Alabama.name << " | Overall - " << Alabama.overall << " ( " << Alabama.win << " - " << Alabama.loss << " ) " << endl << endl;
    cout << MiamiFL.name << " | Overall - " << MiamiFL.overall << " ( " << MiamiFL.win << " - " << MiamiFL.loss << " ) " << endl << endl;
    cout << OklahomaSt.name << " | Overall - " << OklahomaSt.overall << " ( " << OklahomaSt.win << " - " << OklahomaSt.loss << " ) " << endl << endl;
    cout << Auburn.name << " | Overall - " << Auburn.overall << " ( " << Auburn.win << " - " << Auburn.loss << " ) " << endl << endl;
    cout << Tennessee.name << " | Overall - " << Tennessee.overall << " ( " << Tennessee.win << " - " << Tennessee.loss << " ) " << endl << endl;
    cout << PennSt.name << " | Overall - " << PennSt.overall << " ( " << PennSt.win << " - " << PennSt.loss << " ) " << endl << endl;
    cout << Florida.name << " | Overall - " << Florida.overall << " ( " << Florida.win << " - " << Florida.loss << " ) " << endl << endl;
    cout << Georgia.name << " | Overall - " << Georgia.overall << " ( " << Georgia.win << " - " << Georgia.loss << " ) " << endl << endl;
    cout << UNC.name << " | Overall - " << UNC.overall << " ( " << UNC.win << " - " << UNC.loss << " ) " << endl << endl;
    cout << NotreDame.name << " | Overall - " << NotreDame.overall << " ( " << NotreDame.win << " - " << NotreDame.loss << " ) " << endl << endl;
        cout << Clemson.name << " | Overall - " << Clemson.overall << " ( " << Clemson.win << " - " << Clemson.loss << " ) " << endl << endl;
    
    cout << endl << "Type 1 and press Enter to continue." << endl;
    cin >> number;
    goto home;


}
```

Comment: linked: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/250382/football-management-game-in-c/250386#250386

Comment: I found a bug - renaming your team sends the game into a fit!

Comment: I think it is a problem with strings not allowing spaces...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## <strike>`#include <bits/stdc++.h>`</strike>

it is a cheap hack, you're basically avoiding including the separate header file - `string`, `vector`, `iostream`. This doesn't even work on my compiler in visual studio ( msvc ).

[why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>](https://stackoverflow.com/Questions/31816095/Why-Should-I-Not-Include-Bits-Stdc-H.#:%7E:text=By%20using%20this%20header%20file,they%27ll%20be%20less%20productive.)

## <strike>`using namespace std`</strike>

This one is worse, it's making your program a lot more confusing. When there are so many people advising *against* it, why use it? From what I remember you were given the same advice on [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/250382/football-management-game-in-c/250386#250386) question.

If you really really need to not write `std::`, just do it for some functions, preferably in a smaller scope where you can just do `using std::cout`, I still advise **against it**,

[**Read this**!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

---

## Why so many globals?

```cpp
int number, overall;
string team, nextgame;
int opponentoverall;
int score, score2, random, random2, random3, random4, random5, randoml;
float finalscore, finalscore2;
string choice;
int week = 1;
int i = 3;
int u = 0;
int randl;
int champ1, champ2;

int onet = 0;
int twot = 0;
int threet = 0;
int fourt = 0;
int fivet = 0;
int sixt = 0;
int sevent = 0;
int eightt = 0;
int ninet = 0;
int tent = 0;
int onev = 0;
int twov = 0;
int threev = 0;
int fourv = 0;
int fivev = 0;
int sixv = 0;
int sevenv = 0;
int eightv = 0;
int ninev = 0;
int tenv = 0;
string champname, champname2;
string prospect1 = "Jonas Hill - QB";
string prospect2 = "Kyle Matthew - DB";
string prospect3 = "Julius Brown - RB";
string prospect4 = "Reece David -  C";
string prospect5 = "Cole Anderson - FS";
string prospect6 = "Andy Tyler - WR";
string prospect7 = "Macus Reed - FB";
string prospect8 = "Elijah Moore - LB";
string prospect9 = "Larry Steel - RB";
string prospect10 = "Nicholas Dean - LB";
int oner = 0;
int twor = 0;
int threer = 0;
int fourr = 0;
int fiver = 0;
int sixr = 0;
int sevenr = 0;
int eightr = 0;
int niner = 0;
int tenr = 0;
int ones = 0;
int twos = 0;
int threes = 0;
int fours = 0;
int fives = 0;
int sixs = 0;
int sevens = 0;
int eights = 0;
int nines = 0;
int tens = 0;

string one = " ";
string two = " ";
string three = " ";
string four = " ";
string five = " ";
string six = " ";
string seven = " ";
string eight = " ";
string nine = " ";
string ten = " ";
int minutes = 120;
```

There is no need to have so many globals, you can declare them only in the scope where you need them, and in cases where a function might need them, pass it as an argument

## Use an array

```cpp
int onet = 0;
int twot = 0;
int threet = 0;
int fourt = 0;
int fivet = 0;
int sixt = 0;
int sevent = 0;
int eightt = 0;
int ninet = 0;
int tent = 0;
int onev = 0;
int twov = 0;
int threev = 0;
int fourv = 0;
int fivev = 0;
int sixv = 0;
int sevenv = 0;
int eightv = 0;
int ninev = 0;
int tenv = 0;
string one = " ";
string two = " ";
string three = " ";
string four = " ";
string five = " ";
string six = " ";
string seven = " ";
string eight = " ";
string nine = " ";
string ten = " ";
int oner = 0;
int twor = 0;
int threer = 0;
int fourr = 0;
int fiver = 0;
int sixr = 0;
int sevenr = 0;
int eightr = 0;
int niner = 0;
int tenr = 0;
int ones = 0;
int twos = 0;
int threes = 0;
int fours = 0;
int fives = 0;
int sixs = 0;
int sevens = 0;
int eights = 0;
int nines = 0;
int tens = 0;
string prospect1 = "Jonas Hill - QB";
string prospect2 = "Kyle Matthew - DB";
string prospect3 = "Julius Brown - RB";
string prospect4 = "Reece David -  C";
string prospect5 = "Cole Anderson - FS";
string prospect6 = "Andy Tyler - WR";
string prospect7 = "Macus Reed - FB";
string prospect8 = "Elijah Moore - LB";
string prospect9 = "Larry Steel - RB";
string prospect10 = "Nicholas Dean - LB";
```

You can simplify all of this by simply using an [array](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/#:%7E:text=An%20array%20is%20a%20series,index%20to%20a%20unique%20identifier.&text=Like%20a%20regular%20variable%2C%20an,type%20name%20%5Belements%5D%3B) of size `x`. This way when you need a specific team, you just need to slice from it, since you have used names like `oner`, `ones`, `prospect1`, and `onet`, I have no idea what they really do, since all of them are initialized to `0` and the names don't help too much.

Here is what an array used in this would look like

```cpp
constexpr int number_of_prospects = 10;
std::string prospects[ number_of_prospects ];

prospects[ 0 ]  = " Prospect 1 ";
std::cout << prospects[0];
```

> Prospect 1

This is an example of readable code, when someone sees `std::string prospects[ number_of_prospects]`, he knows exactly what it is. Does a person know exactly what your program is doing at some points the second he reads it?

The same array can be applied for all the threads of globals you have, just a simple array of size `10` can work. Even in your class `Team`

```cpp
string week1, week2, week3, week4, week5, week6, week7, week8, next;
```

Simply do

```cpp
std::string weeks[ number_of_weeks ];
```

where `number_of_weeks` would be, guess what- The number of weeks! It would be clear to anyone

## from `void start()`

```cpp
void start() {
    cout << string( 100, '\n' );
    cout << "Choose a School to Coach!" << endl;
    cout << "1- Tennessee" << endl;
enum Schools{ tennessee = 1,auburn,pennst };
        cin >> number;
            if(number == tennessee){
                team = "Tennessee";
                overall = 75;
            }



}
```

The formatting is hurting my eyes

```cpp
void start() 
{
    cout << string(100, '\n');
    cout << "Choose a School to Coach!" << endl;
    cout << "1- Tennessee" << endl;

    enum Schools 
    {
      tennessee = 1, auburn, pennst
    };

    cin >> number;
    if (number == Tennessee) 
    {
        team = "Tennessee";
        overall = 75;
    }
}
```

- Since you only used `tennesse`, what is the use of `auburn, pennst`?
- `overall = 75` what does `75` imply here?  Avoid [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming))

### handle inavlid input

Here, if the user enter's anything else other than an `int`, `std::cin` will fail. This will cause very strange behaviour in your program. It's always good to catch invalid input, you can simply do

```cpp
if (!std::cin >> number) 
{
    std::cout << "Invalid input! \n"; 
}
```

---

## from `void mainmenu()`

```cpp
void mainmenu() {
    
    cout << string( 100, '\n' );
    cout << "FOR THE PLAYER EXPERIENCE, PLEASE PLAY IN FULL SCREEN" << endl;
    cout << "Be the Coach | College Football Manager" << endl;
    cout << "1 - Manage" << endl << "2 - Manual" << endl << "3 - Abort" << endl; 
enum Choices{ manage = 1,manual,abort };
    cin >> number;
        if(number == manage){
            start();
        }
    
}
```

I have the same three problems here

- Inconsistent, unreadble formatting
- `enum Choices { ... };`  has three enumerators when you are using only one
- no handling of bad input

---

## `std::uniform_int_distribution`

C++ has [std::uniform_int_distribution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution) which is better than C`s` rand()`

---

## Naming our variables

```cpp
int rands;
int onel = rand() % 30 + 1;
int two1 = rand() % 30 + 1;
int three1 = rand() % 30 + 1;
int four1 = rand() % 30 + 1;
int five1 = rand() % 30 + 1;
int six1 = rand() % 30 + 1;
int seven1 = rand() % 30 + 1;
int eight1 = rand() % 30 + 1;
int nine1 = rand() % 30 + 1;
int ten1 = rand() % 30 + 1;
int onec = rand() % 10 + 1;
int twoc = rand() % 10 + 1;
int threec = rand() % 10 + 1;
int fourc = rand() % 10 + 1;
int fivec = rand() % 10 + 1;
int sixc = rand() % 10 + 1;
int sevenc = rand() % 10 + 1;
int eightc = rand() % 10 + 1;
int ninec = rand() % 10 + 1;
int tenc = rand() % 10 + 1;
```

Now I see `one`, `onet`, onec` which is making me confused more than ever, always use [meaningful names for functions and variables](https://medium.com/coding-skills/clean-code-101-meaningful-names-and-functions-bf450456d90c). An array can be used here too.

---

## Factor repetition into functions

```cpp
cout << string( 100, '\n' );
    cout << OhioState.name << " | Overall - " << OhioState.overall << " ( " << OhioState.win << " - " << OhioState.loss << " ) " << endl << endl;
    cout << Alabama.name << " | Overall - " << Alabama.overall << " ( " << Alabama.win << " - " << Alabama.loss << " ) " << endl << endl;
    cout << MiamiFL.name << " | Overall - " << MiamiFL.overall << " ( " << MiamiFL.win << " - " << MiamiFL.loss << " ) " << endl << endl;
    cout << OklahomaSt.name << " | Overall - " << OklahomaSt.overall << " ( " << OklahomaSt.win << " - " << OklahomaSt.loss << " ) " << endl << endl;
    cout << Auburn.name << " | Overall - " << Auburn.overall << " ( " << Auburn.win << " - " << Auburn.loss << " ) " << endl << endl;
    cout << Tennessee.name << " | Overall - " << Tennessee.overall << " ( " << Tennessee.win << " - " << Tennessee.loss << " ) " << endl << endl;
    cout << PennSt.name << " | Overall - " << PennSt.overall << " ( " << PennSt.win << " - " << PennSt.loss << " ) " << endl << endl;
    cout << Florida.name << " | Overall - " << Florida.overall << " ( " << Florida.win << " - " << Florida.loss << " ) " << endl << endl;
    cout << Georgia.name << " | Overall - " << Georgia.overall << " ( " << Georgia.win << " - " << Georgia.loss << " ) " << endl << endl;
    cout << UNC.name << " | Overall - " << UNC.overall << " ( " << UNC.win << " - " << UNC.loss << " ) " << endl << endl;
    cout << NotreDame.name << " | Overall - " << NotreDame.overall << " ( " << NotreDame.win << " - " << NotreDame.loss << " ) " << endl << endl;
        cout << Clemson.name << " | Overall - " << Clemson.overall << " ( " << Clemson.win << " - " << Clemson.loss << " ) " << endl << endl;
```

There are two reasons a function should do this

- You have used the same chunk of code more than once
- avoids unnecessarily convoluted code

Just place this in a function with a meaningful name so all you have in your `main()` function is `print_records()`

---

## Don't `goto`!

`goto` is absolutely not required here, especially something like

```cpp
home:

...
...
...
...
...
...
...

goto home;
```

stinks a lot, you really only need a `while` loop

Other than this, there are still many uses of `goto` in your program, seriously re-consider, and replace `goto` with functions.

---

## Simplify program

```cpp
if(Alabama.overall > 100){
        Alabama.overall = 100;
    }
    if(Clemson.overall > 100){
        Clemson.overall = 100;
    }
    if(OhioState.overall > 100){
        OhioState.overall = 100;
    }
    if(NotreDame.overall > 100){
        NotreDame.overall = 100;
    }
    if(OklahomaSt.overall > 100){
        OklahomaSt.overall = 100;
    }
    if(MiamiFL.overall > 100){
        MiamiFL.overall = 100;
    }
    if(Auburn.overall > 100){
        Auburn.overall = 100;
    }
    if(UNC.overall > 100){
        UNC.overall = 100;
    }
    if(Florida.overall > 100){
        Florida.overall = 100;
    }
    if(PennSt.overall > 100){
        PennSt.overall = 100;
    }
    if(Georgia.overall > 100){
        Georgia.overall = 100;
    }
    if(Tennessee.overall > 100){
        Tennessee.overall = 100;
    }
```

Here is how I would like to see it

```cpp
for( auto& team : Teams)
{
    team.overall = std::min(team.overall, max_overall);
}
```

How can we achieve this.

Firstly, you'll need to `#include <algorithm>` and `#include <vector>`

Now, you can clearly see that if we had a better structure earlier, we would be able to do stuff like this much more efficiently. 
What you have to do now is

```cpp
std::vector < Team > teams;

Team x;
x.overall = ..
...
... // initialise Team x

teams.push_back( x )
```

With the above changes, your huge thread of `if` statements can be minimised to

```
for( auto& team : Teams)
{
    team.overall = std::min(team.overall, max_overall);
}
```

- The loop is called a [range-based for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) which you can use to iterate through containers like `std::vector`.
- You can replace `auto` with `Team`, since the type of data in `teams` is `Team`. Using `auto` just makes the compiler do that for us.
- `std::min` will simply return the *smaller* of the two
- Notice how I replaced `100` with `max_overall`. This is because again, `100` doesn't imply anything, `max_overall` is clear